# Being a beginner programmer, how do I start making desktop applications?

Tags: c++

I'm not sure if I came to the proper website to ask this question, but I'll give it a try...
I'm a teenager (getting 17 this year in June) in high school, where I have been studying the basics of C++ for an year... I want to become a programmer in the future, but I feel sort of... lost when it comes about what I should do next. I'm not satisfied with what they teach us at school.
**So my question is: How do I start making simple desktop apps using the C++ programming language?**
I'm not that idiotic kid that believes he can make the next big video game over the summer, without any previous programming experience. Nooooo... I'm talking about simple programs, like a text editor, or a drawing application, or maybe a simple Tetris clone...

Comment: This isn't really a suitable question for StackOverflow, which is intended for specific questions about programming.

Comment: there is no real standard graphics library, so you will have to use one made by people, like wxWidgets, Qt, SFML and more

Comment: You do it step by step moving from very basic stuff to more advanced topics.  You may also want to look at the existing code of an open-source project.

Comment: @MikeNakis: Too broad for Programmers.SE.  See also [Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start).

Answer (score 4):

My suggestions:

- Start with simple console programs, get the content working first.
- Read up on GUI frameworks.  Write a simple program to display a
  window.  Add simple features after the window is displayed, one a time
  after testing.
- Read up on multiple threads.  This prevents "lock up" on your GUI
  while other processing is occurring.
- Read up on "Model View Controller" design pattern.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks! About GUI frameworks: wouldn't they be a little too advanced yet? I tried messing around with GTK+, but I got overwhelmed by the amount of information. The more I read about programming, the more I found out how little I actually know. Anyway, thanks again for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

You tagged `C++` so I would check out learncpp.com they have a lot of great content. You'll want to get familiar with classes, variables, functions, memory management, et cetera before you move on to APIs & frameworks in Windows development or iPhone.

After you've got a firm grip on the basics I would pick up a solid book, many of them out there--read the reviews. I personally went on the path of iOS development first and picked up iOS Programming by Big Nerd Ranch.

Again, though pick up the basics first. Good luck, and search this site for answers you'll most definitely have.